# Fixing My Base 10 to Binary Converter

Tags: python, list

Right now, I have a base 10 to base 2 converter that works, however it always prints none at the end of every conversion.
base_two=0

```
def binary_recursion(base_ten):
    global base_two
    if base_ten==0:
        print(base_two)
        return
    c=0
    while base_ten//2**c>1:
        c+=1
    base_two+=10**c
    if c==0:
        print(base_two)
        return  
    binary_recursion(base_ten-2**c)
```

I tried returning base_two as opposed to printing it, but that doesn't return a number, it also just returns None. Can anyone help me pinpoint my mistake?

Comment: Could you post the error text you get?  You shouldn't be seeing that error there

Comment: I just edited my question

Comment: The problem is if `len(list_queue)>1`, you refer to `head`, but it doesn't have a value because you didn't do `head=None`, because you never entered the other `if` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def node(document_info, next_node):
    return {'data': document_info, 'next': next_node}

def insert(head, new_document_info):
    #insert new document into the linked list head
    #returns the head of the modified list
    if head is None:
        return node(new_document_info, None)
    if new_document_info[1] <= head['data'][1]:
        return node(new_document_info,  head)
    head['next'] = insert(head['next'], new_document_info)
    return head
```

Here's a slightly modified way of doing insertion sort, from my answer to you last question.  You would start with `head = None` and then every time you add a print job do `head = insert(head, document_info)`.  Or after collecting all of your print jobs do something like

```
head = None
for document_info in list_queue:
    head = insert(head, document_info)
```

Comment: For some reason, your code doesn't link my list. It just gives me separate dictionaries of data, and next is always none

Comment: @sneakysnake For posterity, what did you change?

Comment: Actually, I had an idea and thought that it would work, but I'm still fixing bugs. I'm currently making a pointer that walks my linked list and stops when the ptr['next'] is less than the data value you are trying to insert, and then allows that to be inserted. My problem is this.I don't know how to update head. I originally defined my head as None, but I don't know how to change it so that it keeps adding on new nodes.

Comment: @sneakysnake My code gets around that by returning the new `head` and capturing that in the outer `head` variable.  If you aren't using a recursive approach, then you probably need some explicit looping behavior, probably something that looks like `while curr is not None:`

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding new element into queue. Assuming list_queue is a queue.
Queue has put function to add a new element into it.

```
def make_job():
    temp_list=[]
    list_queue = Queue()
    for line in print_list:
        if line[:6]=='submit': #If the command is submit, then the file must be placed in its
            a=line.split()     #correct spot in the linked list 
            del(a[0])
            list_queue.put(a)#Contains file id, and the time required to print
            temp_list.append(list_queue)
            organize(list_queue) #Places the file in its correct spot in the linked list
        else:
            break
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that the function has no attribute "put"

Comment: `import queue` module if you haven't. @sneakysnake

Comment: I just found out we aren't allowed to import queue for this assignment

Comment: I do have another question however

Comment: Well "queue" just adds my files to a temporary list in the order they appear

Comment: you can make the list_queue a global variable instead.

Comment: How would that solve my problem with the head not being defined?

Answer (score 0):

The Python `queue` module has a class called [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/queue.html#queue.PriorityQueue) that does exactly what you're looking for. For your situation, using it would look something like this:

```
class Job(object):
    def __init__(self, name, print_time):
        self.name = name
        self.print_time = print_time

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.print_time < other.print_time

import queue as _queue  # Need to rename the module so it doesn't conflict with your 'queue' function
my_queue = _queue.PriorityQueue()

def make_job():
    for line in print_list:
        if line[:6]=='submit':
            a=line.split()
            del(a[0])
            new_job=queue(a)  # queue(a) now returns a Job, e.g. Job('101', 40), instead of a 2-element list
            my_queue.put(new_job)
        else:
            break
```

Once `my_queue` has been constructed, then repeated calls to `my_queue.get()` will return the `Job`s ordered by `print_time`.

If you want to be able to inspect the contents of the queue without removing elements (`get` removes the element it returns), you could append the `Job`s to a list and call `list_queue.sort()` after every insertion. If this is a performance concern, you could find the right spot in the list yourself and call `list_queue.insert(i, a)`. Deferring to Python's `list.sort` has some advantages, though; namely, it's [stable](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=stable#list.sort).

Lastly, if you don't want to define a new class, you could use `sorted` or `list.sort` with a custom sorting function. This takes the place of the `__lt__` member I defined for `Job`.

```
new_job=queue(a)   # queue(a) is your original function, which returns 2-element lists like ['101', 40]
list_queue.append(new_job)
list_queue.sort(key=lambda a,b: return a[1]<b[1])
```

Comment: I should have been specific that I need to implement my knowledge of linked lists into this assignment, so I can't go the easy way by using a premade sorting function.